# React-Native Navigator not rendering

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to create routing between scenes using Navigator on React-Native (Android), However Navigator won't render the scene, Here is a simple snippet I've created.

```
<View>
  <Navigator
    initialRoute={{ name: 'LoginView' }}
    renderScene={(route, naigator) => {
      <Text styles={{fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Hello, World!</Text>            
    }}
  />
</View>
```

This should render the text `Hello, World!`, but a plain white screen showed up on the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out why this happens, Since renderScene takes in a function it must return a single object of react native UI. So the UI code must be wrapped inside `View` as seen in these examples below:

```
<Navigator
  initialRoute={{ title: 'Awesome Scene'}}
  renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
    <View>
      <Text>Hello, World!</Text>
      <Text>Hi, There</Text>
    </View>
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Navigator` component like this:

```js
<Navigator
    style={{flex: 1}}
    ref={thisRef => {this.navigator = thisRef}}
    initialRoute={{ title: 'Awesome Scene', index: 0}}
    renderScene={(route, navigator) => {

        if(route.index == 0) {
            return <View>
                <Text>Hello, World!</Text>
            </View>
        }

        if(route.index == 1) {
            return <View>
                <Text>Hi, There</Text>
            </View>
        }

        if(route.index == 2) {
            return <View>
                <Text>Hi, There...again!</Text>
            </View>
        }

    }} />
```

That way you can go to another page using

```js
this.navigator.push({title: "Awesome Scene 2", index: 1})
```

or

```js
this.navigator.push({title: "Awesome Scene 3", index: 2})
```

and it will render the correct scene.

Hope this helps!

Comment: what about switch/case?)